# Headless Chrome to Execute Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I want to **Server side render my React Application**. So the request first comes to my web server (written in Rust). I aggregate all the data required to generate the html.

After that I want to execute my React application using headless Chrome.

Every example of headless chrome shows me to "navigate to a page".

Using Nodejs for example using Puppeteer library

```
    (async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Instead of navigating to a URL,  I just want to use the headless Chrome as a JavaScript engine, which  given a JavaScript executes it.

I looked but nowhere I could find a example of that.

Comment: Do you want Chrome to execute your javascript because you want to capture the HTML that is generated by your react application?

Comment: You couldn't find an example because it's nonsensical to use a JavaScript engine like NodeJS to start a headless Chrome instance as a JavaScript engine...

Comment: @Heretic Actually As u said, my web server is in rust, I have used NideJs as an example

Comment: @USER234 yep. That is what I wanted

Comment: Ahh, I just noticed you are using Rust. If you were using NodeJS, React has a library which is designed to produce static html https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring

Comment: Have you done any research on React server-side rendering? There are a lot of resources out there about it. Headless Chrome is just that -- the Chrome browser, just without a UI. It's purpose is to automate things that you would normally need a browser for; Automated testing, rendering screens and taking screenshots of them, etc.. Not running server applications. That's what NodeJS is for. And indeed, [React's solution for server-side rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) suggests using NodeJS...

Comment: I am not using NideJs. This was just an example. I am using Rust Lang.

Answer (score 0):

Well, quick look at [pupetter API](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.1.0/docs/api.md) shows this one:

```
  page.evaluate(pageFunction[, ...args])

    pageFunction <function|string> Function to be evaluated in the page context
    ...
```

Exact link to API: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.1.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args